# How do I loop through an array of dynamically (jQuery) generated texareas and post the values to the same page?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm generating a number of textareas with jQuery. I want to retrieve the values of all the filled out textareas via an on-page POST method (it's kind of a proof of concept, quick and dirty, I wouldn't do this normally), but when I hit submit, I get the value of only one, whichever is the last textarea value posted. I imagine I can do this with an array and a foreach loop, but am unsure how to do it, given all the additions of the jQuery/on-page factors complications in this endeavor. I also imagine it might have something to do with all of the generated textareas having the same name... anyone?

Here's the code-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.textadder').click(function(){
            $("form").append("<p class='introText2'>Enter More Text</p><textarea rows='5' cols='20' name='textForm' class='formText2'></textarea>");
        });



    });/*document ready*/

</script>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['textForm']))
{
$formTxt = $_POST['textForm'];
        echo $formTxt;
}
?>
</head>

<body>


<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="submittedHolder"></div>
    <div class="formBox">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <p class="introText">Please Enter Some Text</p>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="textForm" class="formText"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="submitter" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <div class="textadder"><p>More Text</p></div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div><!--formBox-->
</div><!--wrapper-->


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `textForm[]` in your textarea name instead of `textForm`:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="textForm[]" class="formText"></textarea>
```

After that all "textForm" textareas would be in `$_POST['textForm']` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.textadder').click(function(){
            $("form").append("<p class='introText2'>Enter More Text</p><textarea rows='5' cols='20' name='textForm[]' class='formText2'></textarea>");
        });



    });/*document ready*/

</script>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['textForm']))
{
$formTxt = $_POST['textForm'];
        foreach($formTxt as $txt){
          echo $txt;
    }

}
?>
</head>

<body>


<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="submittedHolder"></div>
    <div class="formBox">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <p class="introText">Please Enter Some Text</p>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="textForm[]" class="formText"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="submitter" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <div class="textadder"><p>More Text</p></div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div><!--formBox-->
</div><!--wrapper-->


</body>

</html>
```

Use array here.
the post object will now be an array.